# How to send sender inside action of UIBarButtonItem inside a UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, selector

Seems like an easy task. A button inside a toolbar (on top of a keyboard) should send the sender to a function. With the code below I receive "unrecognized selector sent to instance" in the debugger.

My goal is to access a specific TextField of a custom cell. This code worked pretty well for identifying e.g. a switch

Declaration of the ToolBar:

```
UIToolbar* itemToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
itemToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
itemToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                     nil];
[itemToolbar sizeToFit];
```

Function of doneWithNumberPad:

```
- (void)doneWithNumberPad:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", [object valueForKey:@"item"]);
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to include colon in your selector method for save button

```
itemToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad:)],
                     nil];
```

`sender` has type of `NSObject`, convert it to `UIBarButtonItem` before converting point.

```
- (void)doneWithNumberPad:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", [object valueForKey:@"item"]);
}
```

Comment: -.- Your right, thank you... Now THAT works. But now CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; creates the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Have to investigate.

Comment: Please type cast the sender to UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: @Peter I have included the code. In the event handler method of the button you can see that sender is assigned to button. You can also do the same by changing the method from `- (void)doneWithNumberPad:(id)sender` to `- (void)doneWithNumberPad:(UIBarButtonItem *)button`. Now there is no need to typecast. More read on type [casting in Objective-C](http://mobisynth.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/typecasting-in-objective-c/)

Comment: But then I receive this failure: No visible @interface for 'UIBarButtonItem' declares the selector 'convertPoint:toView:' In both ways. With changed void function or if I cast the sender (<- right?) Sorry if I bug you.

Comment: Forget my last post. I was on the wrong path here. But I learned something about casting! Thanks!

Comment: @Peter convertPoint:toView: is only available in subclasses on `UIView`. It can be done if you create UIBarButtonItem with a view.